# Let $U$, $V$ be independent random variables following a continuous uniform distribution on $(0,1).$ Let $X=U.V$ then find $f_X$ and $f_V|_X$

Tags: random-variables, density-function

Let $U$, $V$ be independent random variables following a continuous uniform distribution on $(0,1).$ Let $X=U.V$ then find $f_X$ and $f_V|_X$

**My Working**

for $f_X$ we have:

$P(X\leq x)=P(UV\leq x)=\int_{0}^{1} F_V(\frac{x}{u}) \,du=\int_{0}^{x} F_V(\frac{x}{u}) \,du+\int_{x}^{1} F_V(\frac{x}{u}) \,du=\int_{0}^{x} 1\,du+\int_{x}^{1} \frac{x}{u}\,du=-\log{x}$

Is my working for $f_X$ correct? Also how do find $f_V|_X$. Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your reasoning is correct but there is a method by which you can solve both question together. Consider the following system

$$ 
\begin{cases}
x=uv\\
y=v
\end{cases}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
u=\frac{x}{y}\\
v=y
\end{cases}$$

calculate the jacobian obtaining $|J|=\frac{1}{y}$ and thus

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}$$

Now observe that $0<\frac{x}{y}<1$ that is $0<x<y<1$ (a triangle) thus, integrating, immediately you find

$$f_X(x)=\int_x^1\frac{1}{y}dy=-\log x$$

and again immediately you get

$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{1}{-y\log x}$$

Comment: Hey thanks for your kind help. I have one question though? how does $0<\frac{x}{y}<1$ and $0<x<y<1$ hold here?

Comment: Also isn't the conditional pdf $f_Y|_X(y|x)=-\frac{1}{\log{x}}"?$

Comment: @Ameer786: As you can see in the system above, we have that

$$u=\frac{x}{y}$$ and, per hypothesis, $0<u<1$ which means also that

$$0<x<y<1$$

this is the domain of the bivariate density of the vector $\{X,Y\}$

Knowing this you can do any calculation you want...to find the marginal X density you integrate in $dy$ and viceversa, to find the marginal $Y-$ density you integrate $f(x,y)$ in $dx$...

Is it clear now?

Comment: @Ameer786: The conditional density is the ratio I showed, thus $\frac{1}{-y\log x}$

Example: suppose we fix $x=0.5$, substituting you get

$$f_{Y|X}(t)=\frac{1}{t\log2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0.5;1)}(t)$$

Comment: Thanks I got you.